# Synonyms and Referential Integrity

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, synonym

I have multiple database schemas in which some of the tables from one schema s1, need to reference tables from schema s2. I looked up synonym literature and haven't found much details about how I may use public synonyms for selecting, updating and referencing foreign keys, as well as how would the whole thing behave in matters of referential integrity. Should I use a `grant references, update, select, ...` on each table I need? it seems quite a poor way to accomplish the task

Comment: Why do you want to use synonyms rather than specifying the schema name in the constraint definition?

Comment: Actually I need to use the query in a program which its main function is to generate code, so when I try to reference with no synonym, nothing appears. Also, I don't think that creating a grant on each table I need is a good practice.

Comment: Creating a grant on every table you need _is_ good practice. It gives you complete control over data integrity and access. The only case where not granting individually is best practice is when every single table in a schema can be accessed by another schema (or public) and where that fact is ***never*** going to change

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a try, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to grant privilages and specifiy the schema name when querying those tables from the second schema